# Ubuntu 16.04 caching Php Variables?

Tags: php, mysql

I duplicated a folder full of scripts and edited the contents.

ex: /scripts -> /script-new

When I run a php script from this new file I seem to be having some weird issues.

```
php -f /scripts-new/pulldata.php
```

When I do this it seems to be using some variables from the old script that I have changed in the code.

```
/scripts/pulldata.php
$dbtable = "validclickvc";

/scripts-new/pulldata.php
$dbtable = "valid_click_ads";
```

Here is the mysql command that I am running

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $dbtable . " ( COLUMN_NAMES ) " . " VALUES ( COLUMN_VALUES )";
```

And in my error log:

```
Error: INSERT IGNORE INTO validclickvc VALUES ( '--' )
```

What might be causing this?

EDIT:
Here is the whole script if it helps!

```
<?php
    // Set some variables to connect to the FTP
    $yesterday = date("Ymd", strtotime( '-1 days' ));
    $filename = "vc_report_" . $yesterday . ".csv";
    $sourcefile = "/***/" . $filename;
    $localfile = "php://output";
    $ftpserver = "***";
    $ftpusername = "***";
    $ftppassword = "***";

    // Set some variabled to connect to rhe database
    $dbhost = "***";
    $dbname = "***";
    $dbtable = "valid_click_ads";
    $dbusername ="***";
    $dbpassword = "***";
    $fielddelimiter = ",";
    $linedelimiter =  "\r\n";

    // Try to connect to the ftp server
    $conn = ftp_connect($ftpserver) or die("Could not connect");
    echo "Connected to FTP. \n";

    // Try to login to the ftp server
    if (ftp_login($conn, $ftpusername, $ftppassword)) {
        echo "Logged in to FTP. \n";
    } else {
        echo "FTP login unsuccessful. \n";
    }
    ob_start();

    // Try to open download today's report
    $file = ftp_get($conn, $localfile, $sourcefile, FTP_BINARY);

    if ($file) {
        $csvcontent = ob_get_contents();
        echo "File read successfully. \n";
    } else {
        echo "File was not read successfully. \n";
    }

    // Close the file and the connection to the FTP
    ftp_close($conn);
    echo "File and connection to the FTP closed. \n";

    // Connect to the database
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

    if (!$con) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Connected to database. \n";
    }

    // Set row counter
    $rows = 0;

    // Set first
    $first = true;

    // Separate data by line
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvcontent);

    // Insert lines of data
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        if (!$first) {
            $linearray = explode($fielddelimiter, $line);
            print_r ($linearray);
            $source_tag = $linearray[1];
            if ( strpos( $source_tag, 'phone' ) !== false ) {
                $source = "Smart Phone";
            } else if ( strpos( $source_tag, 'desktop' ) !== false ) {
                $source = "Desktop";
            } else {
                $source = "";
            }
            if ( $linearray[14] == "N/A" ) {
                $tq = -1;
            } else {
                $tq = $linearray[14];
            }

            $sql = "SELECT affiliate_id, id, campaign_id, group_id, user_id, website_id FROM keywords WHERE affiliate_id = " . $linearray[7];
            $result = $con->query($sql);
            if ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                $keyword_id = $row[ 'id' ];
                $group_id = $row[ 'group_id' ];
                $campaign_id = $row[ 'campaign_id' ];
                $user_id = $row[ 'user_id' ];
                $website_id = $row[ 'website_id' ];
            } else {
                $keyword_id = "";
                $group_id = "";
                $campaign_id = "";
                $user_id = "";
                $website_id = "";
            }

            $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO " . $dbtable . " ( market, source, device, searches, impressions, clicks, revenue, tq, website_id, user_id, campaign_id, group_id, affiliate_id, keyword_id ) " . " VALUES ( '" . $linearray[5] . "', " . $source . "', " . $linearray[4] . "', " . $linearray[8] . "', " . $linearray[9] . "', " . $linearray[10] . "', " . $linearray[12] . "', " . $tq . "', " . $website_id . "', " . $user_id . "', " . $campaign_id . "', " . $group_id . "', " . $affiliate_id . "', " . $keyword_id . "' )";
            echo $sql;
            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                $rows++;
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
            }
        } else {
            $first = false;
        }
    }

    $con->close();
    echo "Inserted a total of " . $rows . " records.\n"
?>
```

Comment: You're probably still `include`ing a file from the old folder somewhere. Rename `/scripts` to `/scripts-old` and see where your code complains about a missing file.

Comment: Can some of these php files be symbolic links in the old folder?

Comment: @DCoder there are no includes in this file. I just checked (:

Comment: @regulus what do you mean? No links in the code. I could include all the code if that would help. it's only about 100 lines

Comment: @LucyTurtle I mean file system symbolic links, not talking about what you have inside your code.

Comment: @regulus I was able to run other scripts from the folder, both a python script and a php script. Neither seemed to have such a weird issue

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you've saved the changes to `scripts-new/pulldata.php`? Do you have any [opcode cache extension](http://php.net/manual/refs.basic.php.php) enabled? Tried renaming the file, eg `pulldata-new.php`?

Comment: `$sql` says `INSERT INTO`, the log message says `INSERT IGNORE INTO`. Is that also something you changed between the two scripts?

Comment: Alright guys. I renamed the folder again along with all the files and the issue stopped. Idk why but we did it?